# Question about strange behavior of Atomic boolean while concurrent access is done

Tags: java, concurrency

I got such code:

```
public class ConcurrencyCheck {
    private volatile static AtomicBoolean top=new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private  int i=0;

    public class Toppler extends Thread{
        private final boolean bool;

        public Toppler(boolean myBool,String name) {
            super(name);
            bool=myBool;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!isInterrupted()){

                i++;
                synchronized (top) {
                    if (top.get() == bool) top.set(!top.get());
                    System.err.println(super.getName() + "  "+ bool +"->" + top + ". i is " + i);
                }

                try {
                    sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConcurrencyCheck cc = new ConcurrencyCheck();
        Thread t1= cc.new Toppler(true,"thread1");
        Thread t2= cc.new Toppler(false,"thread2");
        Thread t3= cc.new Toppler(true,"thread3");
        Thread t4= cc.new Toppler(false,"thread4");
        Thread t5= cc.new Toppler(true,"thread5");
        Thread t6= cc.new Toppler(false,"thread6");
        Thread t7= cc.new Toppler(true,"thread7");
        Thread t8= cc.new Toppler(false,"thread8");
        t1.start();
        ...
        t8.start();
        sleep(950);
        t1.interrupt();
        ...
        t8.interrupt();
    }
}
```

It is designed to check how AtomicBoolean works. Class Toppler is a thread that periodically topples Atomic boolean. The block of code which topples boolean is synchronized. As I guessed, each output line have to topple value of "top" variable, so output have to be "true->false false->true true->false...". But for some reason sometimes I can see such output:

```
thread1  true->false. i is 1
thread8  false->true. i is 8
thread7  true->false. i is 8
thread4  false->true. i is 8
thread6  false->true. i is 8
thread3  true->false. i is 8
thread5  true->false. i is 8
thread2  false->true. i is 8
thread1  true->false. i is 9
thread8  false->true. i is 10
thread7  true->false. i is 11
thread4  false->true. i is 12
thread6  false->true. i is 13
thread3  true->false. i is 14
```

The question is: why two consequent false->true or true->false output lines are possible?

Comment: Your use of the words "top" and "toppler" is confusing. What do you mean? Is your goal that each task flips the boolean value if that value matches the given boolean of the task's constructor?

Comment: Because it didn't flip as the threads run out-of-order. The `if` condition did not pass, but the printout is confusing by assuming it would have.

Comment: Yep. Toppler is a class which inverse boolean value, if it is equal to 'bool' variable that is set while constructing Toppler class.

Comment: "I missed parenthesis" - that's one of the reasons a lot of static code checkers always require the use of parentheses. You could easily produce such situation so I'd recommend making it a rule for yourself (and your team) so that a missing parenthesis on a block raises a red flag in your head.

Comment: "I'll always use parenthesis with if blocks." - that's a good start but I'd suggest you make it a rule to always use them to prevent the same situation with other constructs (e.g. loops). Single-expression lambdas might be an exception since the compiler will force you to add braces for more than 1 statement anyway.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

You asked:

> The question is: why two consequent false->true or true->false output lines are possible?

Two reasons:

- You cannot expect threads to run in any particular order. The JVM and host OS schedule threads for execution time on a CPU core at their own whim, in a manner unpredictable to us.
- I suspect that calls to `System.err.println`, like `System.out.println`, do *not* always appear on the console in chronological order.

➥ If you want to coordinate activities between threads, such as alternating their work in a particular pattern, you must take additional steps.

## Details

The goal of your experimental code is not quite clear to me. Apparently each task is constructed with a target boolean value. If that task finds the currently flag variable `top` to match our target boolean, then we flip `top` to the opposite.

As for the interleaving of threads in numbered order of 1, 8, 7, 4, and so on, that is to be expected. There is no predicting the order of execution of threads. Which thread gets scheduled next for execution on a CPU core, and for how long to execute, is up to the JVM and host OS, depending on their algorithms and current runtime conditions. Never expect a set of threads to run in a certain order.

Your code has several issues.

One is that you are incrementing a shared `int` variable named `i` with no concurrency protection. You declare that `int` var as a class member of `ConcurrencyCheck` and then call `i++` in each of your threads. That code incrementing `i` is not [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), sharing a mutable resource across threads. That is why you are seeing failure with the values there. You should be using an `AtomicInteger` for that purpose of incrementing a counter.

Regarding `synchronized (top) {`, there is no need to mark that code `synchronized` as your code is currently written. The reason to use `AtomicBoolean` rather than a mere `Boolean` is to to be automatically thread-safe, obviating the need for `synchronized`. However, you are trying to do some other things at the same time: increment a counter, and report your progress with current values. So for *that* reason, to group together multiple other operations together atomically, you *do* need a `synchronized`, but you do *not* need a `synchronized` simply for using the `AtomicBoolean` by itself alone.

Regarding `if (top.get() == bool) top.set(!top.get());`, you should be using one of the sophisticated methods on `AtomicBoolean` to perform a get-and-set kind of operation atomically. That is the job of `AtomicBoolean`, to make such operations atomic. Specifically I believe you are looking for [`AtomicBoolean#compareAndExchange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndExchange(boolean,boolean)) to set a new value if the expected value is found, and then return the found value.

Your message string for reporting results is confusing. I would write something more like this, where your `bool` var is renamed to `expectedValue` per terminology of the Javadoc for `compareAndExchange`. Caveat: I am no expert here, so verify my logic and verify my understanding of that Javadoc.

```java
boolean witnessValue = top.compareAndExchange( this.expectedValue , ! this.expectedValue );
String msg = "Thread ID # " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " expected: " + this.expectedValue + ", found: " + witnessValue + ", ended with top being: " + witnessValue + ". countAttempts: " + countAttempts + "." + " Now: " + Instant.now();
```

Regarding `private volatile static AtomicBoolean top`, there is no need to mark `AtomicBoolean` as `volatile` here. By initializing where declared, you have ensured there is already one `AtomicBoolean` object assigned. You never replace that object with another, so there is no chance of any thread having the visibility problem where the CPU core caches have different values. You should mark the field `final` to prevent you from mistakenly swapping out another object.

Another issue is that in modern Java we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. The executor service framework was added to Java 5 to relieve us of the chores of juggling threads. Define your task as a `Runnable` (or `Callable`), and submit an instance to the `ExecutorService` implementation of your choice (see `Executors` class).

Do not expect your console output to be in chronological order. As for order of output on `System.err`, I imagine like `System.out` that it is *not* chronological. I do not know if it is due to threads being suspended between the message  content being generated inside the `println` parens and actually being passed to the `println` method, or if it is due to internal buffering issues, but I can tell you that I often see a series of `println` calls appearing *not* in chronological order on the console. I recommend (a) Always include a call to `Instant.now` or `System.nanoTime`, and (b) Collect your messages in a thread-safe `List`.

Comment: Does the use of `if (top.get() == bool) top.set(!top.get());` really make `synchronized(top)` unnecessary? I agree that it could be solved more elegantly e.g. with `compareAndSet()` but given the OP's code I'd say without additional synchronization multiple threads could get into the if-statement's body concurrently - or did I miss something?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, the `i` *is* shared, is it not? Exists as a member field on `ConcurrencyCheck` but is incremented with `i++` on each of the various threads.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Why are the strings interleaved even though the if statement and the println are in a synchronized block? Probably, this has something to do with stream buffering, but System.err is auto flushing on println, so I don't understand the observed behavior.

Comment: @ciamej I believe the 8 8 8 8 series of output is due to incrementing in an non-thread-safe manner. As for the interleaving of threads in numbered order of 1, 8, 7, 4, and so on, that is to be expected. There is no predicting the order of execution of threads. Which thread gets scheduled next for execution on a CPU core, and for how long to execute, is up to the JVM and host OS, depending on their algorithms and current runtime conditions. Never expect a set of threads to run in order.

Comment: @ciamej As for order of output on `System.err`, I imagine like `System.out` that it is *not* chronological. I do not know if it is due to threads being suspended between the message  content being generated inside the `println` parens and actually being passed to the `println` method, or if it is due to internal buffering issues, but I can tell you that I often see a series of `println` calls appearing *not* in chronological order on the console. I recommend (a) Always include a call to `Instant.now` or `System.nanoTime`, and (b) Collect your messages in a thread-safe `List`.

Comment: 8 8 8 8 series is OK because code was designed to understand concurrency problems like race condition and shared state. Problem was in                              "synchronized (top) {
       if (top.get() == bool) top.set(!top.get());
       System.err.println(super.getName() + "  "+ bool +"->" + top + ". i is " + i);
  }". Println supposed to be in parenthesis of if block.

Comment: @AndrewLevchenko See my latest edit, suggesting a rewriting of your message text. You can, and should (I think), report every time through without exception.

Comment: Ok, so it was a simple case of misplaced parentheses. i agree that println statements from different threads in general can occur in arbitrary order, however in this case, when all the printlines are in critical section within a synchronized block the order is no longer arbitrary.

Comment: There’s more sense in doing `if(top.compareAndSet(bool, !bool)) System.err.println(super.getName() + "  "+ bool +"->" + !bool + ". i is " + i);` as `compareAndSet` returns whether the flip happened. It’s, however, important to keep in mind that since now the flip and print statement are not guarded by a synchronization, they may be printed out of order even though the original error is not present anymore.